# Self-published NPM package not importing anything when added

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I published a very simple NPM package with the following:

```js
module.exports = { foo: "baz" };
```

When webpacked, it looks like the line below, and this file is referenced as the `main` property in `package.json`.

```js
(()=>{var r={579:r=>{r.exports={foo:"baz"}}},o={};!function t(e){if(o[e])return o[e].exports;var p=o[e]={exports:{}};return r[e](p,p.exports,t),p.exports}(579)})();
```

Now, in a separate project when I install the package and try to import it, I get nothing:

```js
const obj = require('mypackage')
console.log(obj)
// => {}
```

```js
import obj from 'mypackage'
console.log(obj)
// => {}
```

What is missing here?  How do I get this exported object to come through to the installed NPM package?

Comment: Honestly, for stuff like this, I just use `microbundle`

Comment: This is specific to your Webpack config and not anything else, but it's not listed. That the bundle is minified doesn't help (you shouldn't minify entry point) but that it doesn't refer "module" or "exports"  variables is the problem here. It's empty module.exports object that is imported, while your exports are assigned to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than messing with webpack config, my solution was indeed to use [Microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle) as suggested by Derek in the comments.

It worked immediately, so the "answer" is that there was something wrong with the webpack config, though I don't know what it was.